# VirtualEnv python2.7 error

Tags: python, virtualenv, ubuntu-10.04, python-2.7

I have installed Python 2.7 on my ubuntu 10 LTS

```
tar xzf Python-2.7.tgz
cd Python-2.7
./configure
make
sudo make altinstall
```

The python seems to be correctly installed.

I have installed virtualenv.

Everything works fine if I create an envrionment using:

```
sudo virtualenv env
```

But if I try to use:

```
sudo virtualenv env --p python2.7 --no-site-packages
```

I have the follwing error:

```
ImportError: No module named warnings
ERROR: The executable env1/bin/python2.7 is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/home/me/Documents/test1' (should be '/home/me/Documents/test1/env')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

On another machine, everything works fine with Python2.7 so I guess there something wrong with my python2.7 install or with my virtualenv install, but I have no idea how to start looking where the problem is hidden

Answer (score 1):

I installed a brand new system ubuntu10.04 LTS
I installed python

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2.7

I install virtualenv
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv

The command 
sudo virtualenv env -p python2.7

Fails and returns :

ImportError: No module named warnings
ERROR: The executable env/bin/python2.7 is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/home/me/Documents/code/jord' (should be '/home/me/Documents/code/jord/env')

UPDATE

I edited the source of virtualenv.py and added  'warnings' and '_weakrefset' in the list of REQUIRED_MODULES and it seems to work now

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you want to compile python yourself? It is ubuntu so I would install setuptools, virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper using apt-get. Then follow http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/ to setup virtualenvwrapper properly. Python 2.7 will automatically be included for you in any VE you build.

Comment: Reading some forums, it seemed that compiling python2.7 was the best way to install it on ubuntu LTS

Comment: I have install python2.7 using DeadSnakes PPA, I still run into the same prob